# vb.net daily time record

Tags: vb.net, date, time

I need some ideas/suggestions on how to properly deal with this.. i have my able

```
Table: dtr
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id_dtr | dtr_date | time_in_am | time_out_am | time_in_pm | time_out_pm | employee_id 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1   |2012-10-17| 15:20:41   |
```

I'm wondering how would I be supposed to insert date here. I'm using sql query in vb.net.

```
cmd.commandText = "insert into dtr(dtr_date)values(curdate())"
cmd.executenonquery()
cmd.commandText = "update dtr set time_in_am = curTime(),employee_id=@emp_id where id_dtr=last_insert_id()"
cmd.executenonquery()
```

My problem is how I will fill the fields in my `time_out_am`,`time_in_pm`,`time_out_pm` fields. So when if I have `time_in_am` the next `time_out_am` will be filled and so on. I'm kinda new in vb.net since we are just migrating from vfp.

Comment: Sorry, i don't quite follow, what is your concrete question? So for instance, what _space_ do you want to _fill_ how?

Comment: the fields for my time_out_am,time_in_pm,time_out_pm...i dont know the proper way to insert data. those fields will be filled as long as the same employee_id and in the current date only..

Comment: Your queries look right - you're inserting a new record when an employee first clocks in.  Otherwise, you have to update the desired field in that record for the other in/out values.  BTW, if your id_dtr is unique, you can use that for your updates and drop the check on employee_id.  Is your question how to hook the SQL into your code?

Comment: i got your point but i really dont know how to form it in vb.net-mysql combination...what i want is `"insert into time_out_am if there is record in time_in_am, else insert time_in_pm if there is record in time_in_am and time_out_am, else insert time_out_pm if there is record in time_in_am and time_out_am and time_in_pm where emp_id is the same and date is in current"`

Comment: Not 100% sure that's the best way to go about it (putting that kind of logic in the data layer), but if that's the direction you need to go, why not use a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your problem maybe you may change the update using a check function.
Something like this:  cmd.commandText = "update dtr set " & CurrentValue & " = curTime(),employee_id=@emp_id where id_dtr=last_insert_id()". 
CurrentValue is a function that returns a string with the name of the current field to fill.